# what's the origin of "400 Bad Request Error " error?

Tags: .net, angular, http, put

Am trying to send data to my service so that its value get updated

**userController(.net)**

```
public async Task<ActionResult<bool>> Put([ObjectIdValidator]int id, [FromBody] User User)
        {
            return await _UserService.UpdateUser(User);
        }
```

**User.service.ts**

```
updateUser(UserId: any, user: any) {
        return this._httpClient.put(this.userUrl + `/${userId}`, user);
    }
```

**User.component.ts**

```
editUser() {
        this.userService.updateUser(this.userId,user)
        .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
        .subscribe((res:any) => {
              //
            });
        });

    }
```

Am pretty sure am sending the right data to the right url but something is not working and i can't figure it out

Comment: What did you find when you ran this all in debug?

Comment: PUT http://localhost:....... 400 (Bad Request) ERROR Bad Request

Comment: I just learned how to use postman and I figured where my problem is ..thanks for the help

Comment: Where's the problem? That information may help somebody else some day.

Comment: an error showed in postman indicating that the id am sending is not valid even though it does exist in my database (still trying to figure it out )

Comment: What is `ObjectIdValidator`? Does this play a part in the 400? Have you also inspected your browsers network tab to see what the request looks like when executed from the Angular app? Things to check: ID is correct, URL is correct, payload is sent, ID matches the criteria of the `ObjectIdValidator`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error 400 is supposed to be client error. For example here, you might send invalid user object. Please log user before sending and see what is wrong.

Comment: an error showed in postman indicating that the id am sending is not valid even though it does exist in my database (still trying to figure it out )